# Apps Script Insert 2 columns if header contains x

Tags: google-apps-script

I have put together some code to insert x number of columns if "*y*" text matches a value in the header column.  The code works, however, is there any way I can get the code to match say only the last two words?  So I need to search if the header value contains the words "Teacher Target" and if it matches insert two columns before that column, however I have other columns that contain the heading "Teacher Target - EFG" I do not need columns inserting before these.

The code I am using is:

```
function insCols(e) {

  var lastColumn = ss.getLastColumn();
  var headers = ss.getRange('1:1').getValues();

  var searchVal = ui.prompt("Enter name of column to be inserted").getResponseText();
  var noCols = ui.prompt("Number of columns to be inserted").getResponseText();

  var names = headers[0];
  var loopCounter = names.length - 1

  for (var i = loopCounter; i >= 1; i--) {
    if(names[i].indexOf(searchVal) > -1) {
      ss.insertColumnsBefore(i + 1, noCols);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Fazila

Comment: Not quite clear on what you need here - do you need it to only insert the columns if the text is **exactly** "Teacher Target" or if the **last two words** are "Teacher Target"?

Comment: Where the last two words are Teacher Target.  Thanks ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using Headerstring.slice(-14)==“Teacher Target”

This function runs off of an onEdit installable trigger.

```
function insCols(e) {
  e.source.toast('flag1');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet222') return;
  var hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var nc=0;
  hA.forEach(function(e,i){
    if(e.slice(-14)=="Teacher Target") {
      var msg=Utilities.formatString('Enter names of columns to be inserted next to left of column %s separated by commas.',i+1+nc);
      var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt(msg,SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
      if(resp.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
        var nA=resp.getResponseText().split(',');
        var cn=i+1+nc;
        nA.forEach(function(n,j){
          sh.insertColumnBefore(cn+j);  
          sh.getRange(1,cn+j).setValue(nA[j]);
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
          nc++;
        });

      }
      if(resp.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.CANCEL) {

      }
    }
  });
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to keep the input box as I want the code to be available in other sheets and it would not always be inserting columns before columns containing Teacher Target

Comment: You can still keep the input box is it just be a way of finding those headers that have teacher target as the last 14 or so characters

Comment: A really silly question but where would I insert that line?

Comment: The workaround I've currently used is to insert a + sign after Teacher Target and search for "Teacher Target+" which has fortunately worked but would be interested to learn if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Thanks Cooper for everything you've been amazingly helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want columns to be added only if the corresponding header ends up with the words "Teacher Target", you could achieve this by just changing this line:

```js
if (names[i].indexOf(searchVal) > -1) {
```

To this one:

```js
if (names[i].slice(-14) == "Teacher Target") {
```

Another option would be using `substring`, but I think `slice` is the easiest way in your situation:

```js
if (names[i].substring(names[i].length, names[i].length - 14) == "Teacher Target") {
```

#### Notes:

I am assuming that you didn't provide the full code (the code as it is cannot work, it is using variables that are not defined).

#### Reference:

- [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

I hope this is of any help.